# How to mock RabbitAdmin class in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, rabbitmq, spring-boot-actuator, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to create a mock object for RabbitAdmin class in JUnit.

`@Mock RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin; @InjectMocks MyOriginalClass classObj;`

The above is what I have declared.

`Mockito.when(rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties("responseQueueName").get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT")).thenReturn(0);`

When executing the above line in my test method I'm getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me break down your mock call into pieces

```
Mockito.when(
    rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties("responseQueueName")
        .get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT")
).thenReturn(0);
```

In the middle part, you have the following:

```
rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties("responseQueueName")
```

`rabbitAdmin` itself is a mock object, that means every method has default behaviour to return `null`. If you have not specified any behavior for `rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(anyString())` or `rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties("responseQueueName")`, then this call will return `null`.

Then you have the next part:

```
rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties("responseQueueName")
    .get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT")
```

If you don't have any behaviour specified, then you are calling partically `null.get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT")` which will get you your `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this null pointer, you could do something

```
// creating a properties mock
// this could also be a normal constructor call
Properties properties = Mockito.mock(Properties.class);
// returning 0 when QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT is called
Mockito.when(properties.get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT")).thenReturn(0);

// returning properties when responseQueueName is called
Mockito.when(rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties("responseQueueName")).thenReturn(properties);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. Please edit this alone in your post for that to be accurate.
`Mockito.when(properties.get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT")).thenReturn(0);`